# Synchronised local copy of MySQL / PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization

I have a web based CRM coded in PHP, running off a MySQL database. The server is hosted in the same city as the company HQ but the company's internet connection is average (10Mbps down, 2Mbps up, 30ms ping to the server, all on a good day). The boss is happy with the results but now wants it to 'run super fast in the office' but we still need it to be viewable on the internet.

Short of moving the web server from our host and on to the local office network, which isn't a great option because then it would be super slow for everyone outside of the office, does anyone know a way to achieve this? I was thinking of setting up a local copy of the site and having the MySQL databases synchronise, but this sounds like a logistical nightmare.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Happy to provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup dual-master replication with MySQL to accomplish this.

I would not attempt it without a fast, reliable line (which it sees you have).  I would certainly setup and load test temporary servers to prove the configuration works.

For more information

http://devel.reinikainen.net/40

http://www.neocodesoftware.com/replication/

Comment: Thanks for the info Eric! Good to know this kind of thing is possible and what it's actually called.

Comment: I'll probably end up going with @Zak's suggestions but I'm accepting this answer because it's most relevant to the title of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not joking around here.

Step 1) Have your boss define in written format what super fast means. This could(should?) include page load times for specific pages.

Step 2) Determine where there is a deficiency in speed. You think you know, but you don't. Measure it and record results. Use firebug in firefox to check page load and transfer times.

Step 3) Identify how you can speed up the app based on SPECIFIC measurements you looked at.

Comment: Thanks Zak. A very good point about properly defining the problem! I'll try to get the boss to put numbers on it. I've been benchmarking with PHP's microtime and Firebug which has paid dividends.

Unfortunately the old system is a native windows program with an in-office SQL server. Hard to compete with that speed wise!